# Trying to find a book I read ages ago about telepathic aliens on a colony world

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, telepathy, space-colonization

What I can remember is that the main character travels to the new world colony via a space ship. When she (I think) arrives and is woken up she finds out that she is one of a small percentage of travelers that suffer memory loss from the trip.  She can however relearn what she needs too and does so.  Also the main character is some kind of scientist.

On the colony world are aliens. They are intelligent but are treated like animals and confined to reservations.  The aliens can read minds and communicate with each other via some sort of telepathy. They don't have advanced technology and are hunter gatherers.

Hope someone can help.

Thank you

Edits

Read it between 15 and 20 years ago.

Can't remember what the cover looked like.

There were scrolling news tickers in the city centers and around public transport stations.

I think the aliens were furry.

I believe the novel was an extended metaphor for European colonisation.

May or may not have been a teen novel.

At one point in the story a plane carrying government officials crashes over the desert.

The aliens live in desert areas in mud huts and befriend the main character.

The aliens have elders who are important to their community.

Printed in english.

As the main character learns more about herself she views her old self as single minded,  ruthless and insensitive.

Comment: Do you remember when you read it? Or possibly what the cover looks like? Take a look at [this excellent guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) that may help you add in some more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much trawling of the internet I have found it!

**Deucalion** is a 1995 young adult science fiction novel by **Brian Caswell**.

Comment: 1995 = ages ago? Waves cane.